# Assigning colours to data sets

Tags: r

I've got the following code that generates a random data set with a graph of the following,

```
x1=abs(rnorm(200))
x2=abs(rnorm(200))-7*x1^2
plot(x1,x2)
```

[image]

My goal is to separate the data so that the first 100 points are blue and the remaining 100 points are red in a data.frame. So I have two quick questions,
1) How do I separate the data so as I move along x1 the first 100 points are blue and the other are red? I've added an image below for clarification, mind my artistic talent with the snipping tool.
[image]
2) If after the colours are assigned, is a simple z=data.frame(x1,x2, colours) enough to get the data into a dataset so that I may run the data using some basic machine learning tools, such as SVM, Bagging and Boosting?

Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x1 = abs(rnorm(200)))
dat$x2 <- abs(rnorm(200)) - 7*dat$x1^2
dat$col <- ifelse(rank(dat$x1) <= 100, "blue", "red")
plot(x2 ~ x1, data = dat, col = col)
# also: plot(dat$x1, dat$x2, col = dat$col)
```

[image: sample plot]

The "first 100" is subjective depending on your needs and the context of the data. One might also want the euclidean distance from origin (pythagorean), manhattan distance, or some other valuation. Or `x1 <= mean(x1)` or `x1 <= median(x1)`. Lots of ways, this is just one way, where we use `ifelse` to differentiate/assign.

Comment: Hey @r2evans, thank you as this is almost exactly what I want. However, I was looking for the points in the top left to be all blue and then as I move along the x1 axis closer to 3 all the points would be red. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh alright I see, I didn't consider using the rank function to get around the ordering of the data. I started to build the data table using the order function, which would work as well but is a bit longer. Thank you for this.

Comment: Ahhhh ... `order` and `rank` return very different vectors. Try `rank(c(1,3,5,2,4,6))` and then `order(c(1,3,5,2,4,6))` to see that the second is not quite right for this use. For example, with `rank`, the second element in its return corresponds to the second element in the vector (3 here). With `order`, the second element does not at all correspond to the second element of the input vector, so it should not be used in the `ifelse` (which does a mapping of input-to-output, where corresponding values is important).

Comment: Something else to consider: (1) your lean to using `data.frame` to track colors (and shapes, per your previous question) is spot-on, it can and will be frustrating trying to track points and lines and shapes and colors unless they are all tied together fairly well. (2) It might be simpler to use the `ggplot2` package, which can take care of assigning unique colors (shapes, ...) per some criteria. It's not unreasonable to use `ggplot(dat, aes(x1, x2)) + geom_point(aes(color = col, shape = col))` for a similar plot. It has a steep learning curve from base R, but (IMHO) is very worth the effort.

Comment: Hey @r2evans, thanks for the input. It is something I will consider as I've used ggplot2 a couple of times however it appears that it is something I should invest more time into. Cheers, once again.